# Anchor tag redirects to wrong path

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect to using anchor tag. But I path get changed while redirecting.

for eg.my path is '*company/limit -l.doc*'

it redirects as

'*company/limit+-l.doc*'.

File is uploaded as company/limit -l.doc in folder. It adds '+' in whitespace.

```
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $url='resume/'.$_FILES['resume']['name'];
 $url1="//sample.com/domain/".$url;
 $body.='resume :<a href="'.$url1.'" download>Download</a> <br>';
```

Comment: Ok, do one thing write `echo $url1; die();` after `$url1="//doczbox.com/bluemounts/".$url;`and run the file then it displays the url which you use inside anchor tag. Then copy that link and paste into new tab and check the link open correctly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to URL Encode that document name because it has a space http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php which will convert "limit -l.doc" into "limit%20-l.doc"

```
$body.='resume :<a href="//sample.com/domain/company/'.'.rawurlencode($url).'" download>Download</a> <br>';
```

the slashes '/' will get encoded by rawurlencode too so you will need to keep the folder structure out of the URL encoding

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80b9097b5239f924184a5b074bd0b7225261abcc